Discord-py-api program is completely not work
When I wrote a discord auto replier with python lib discord-py-api it looks like it didnt detect the message received...
My code:

import discord


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return  

        else:
            await message.channel.send(self.user + ' is not here now. Please message later. Thank you.')
            print('One message replied to ' + message.author)



print("""
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          Discord-auto-replier
                           By orangetheorange
           https://github.com/orangetheorange/discord-replier
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

[*] Thank you for using, if you find any bugs, please report to me.
[*] Please read token.md for your discord token.

[!] If you enter a token, please keep it secretly, if someone has it he can
have full access to your account.           
""")

global token
token = ""
with open('token.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as tok:
    if tok.read() == "":
        with open('token.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as tok:
            token = input('Put your discord token here: ')
            tok.write(token)
    else:
        with open('token.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as toke:
            token = toke.read()
print('Used token: ' + token)
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run(token)



I tried to change some of the small details like remove ".channel" but nothing worked.. It didn't even print the message replied when a message is received... I am expecting it to work properly that it will reply automatically.
I also tried this:
#!/bin/python

import discord


print("""
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          Discord-auto-replier
                           By orangetheorange
           https://github.com/orangetheorange/discord-replier
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

[*] Thank you for using, if you find any bugs, please report to me.
[*] Please read token.md for your discord token.

[!] If you enter a token, please keep it secretly, if someone has it he can
have full access to your account.           
""")

global token
token = ""
with open('token.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as tok:
    if tok.read() == "":
        with open('token.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as tok:
            token = input('Put your discord token here: ')
            tok.write(token)
    else:
        with open('token.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as toke:
            token = toke.read()
print('Used token: ' + token)
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    else:
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author} is not here now. Please message later. Thank you.')
        print(f'One message replied to {message.author}')

client.run(token)




"nothing worked" – well, what happens that shouldn't, or what doesn't happen that should?

Cuz it was supposed to be like reply when received a message from sb, but it didn't reply and didnt even print out the message repllied so the error should be in the on_message(), just my guess. This is my first time using discord.py so not sure... Thx

Add a print(message) in the beginning of your on_message event to see if the message is at least detected. Also make sure that your bot has enough permissions.

I did try this but it seems like it didn't detect it. Thank you for finding the problem but if u can i am looking for a solution. Thx

whici also it did logon properly tho

Well you don't really need to put it in the MyClient. Just do:
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    else:
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author} is not here now. Please message later. Thank you.')
        print(f'One message replied to {message.author}')


It is because i didnt use the on_message? So if i dont create that class it is ran automatically right? But if i remove it then the code for the client = MyClient wont run if i want to change it i need to do client = discord.Client() right?

well it is still not doing anything.

@user25939497 instead of doing client = discord.client, do client = commands.Bot

where do you get the "commands"? is it an another library bcuz it is not an attribute from discord...

@user25939497 from discord.ext import commands
